# Best way for text extraction (classification) over a SQL query in java

Tags: java, sql, text-parsing

I have several SQL queries like this (about 10.000):

```
SELECT (COLUMN BODY) 
FROM (TABLES BODY) 
WHERE...
```

The `where` part is optional.

I need to extract the "COLUMN BODY" AND "TABLES BODY" from the query, but those are dynamic (I have found SQL functions and subqueries a lot)

Think as getting an vector with the divided query or something like that:

```
String result = [SELECT, "COLUMN BODY", FROM, "TABLES BODY", WHERE, ... ]
```

The purpose, I'm working in an "SQL translator" and I need extract those parts from that dynamic queries. I have tried string splitting and other but the result is so frustrating, so I'm looking for an alternative to achieve that. I'm working on a java project.

What is the best way to get that?

**Edit**

Those are examples of the queries:

```
SELECT COMPANIA, ANO, TIPO_COBRO, CODIGO, DESCRIPCION FROM SF_DESCRIPCIONES_ESTAND

SELECT AUT_FAMILIARES.COMPANIA, AUT_FAMILIARES.DCTO_EMPLEADO, AUT_FAMILIARES.SUCURSAL_EMPLEADO, AUT_FAMILIARES.IDENTIFICACION,  AUT_FAMILIARES.SUCURSAL, AUT_FAMILIARES.CONSECUTIVO,   AUT_FAMILIARES.DCTO_IDENTIDAD,   AUT_FAMILIARES.PARENTESCO,   AUT_FAMILIARES.NOMBRE,   AUT_FAMILIARES.FECHANCTO,   AUT_FAMILIARES.SEXO,   AUT_FAMILIARES.OBSERVACIONES,   AUT_FAMILIARES.POLIZA,   AUT_FAMILIARES.SALUD,   AUT_FAMILIARES.PORCENTAJE,   AUT_FAMILIARES.OCUPACION,   AUT_FAMILIARES.TELEFONO,   AUT_FAMILIARES.POS,   AUT_FAMILIARES.AUXILIO_EDUCATIVO,   AUT_FAMILIARES.APELLIDO1,   AUT_FAMILIARES.APELLIDO2,   AUT_FAMILIARES.DIRECCION,   AUT_FAMILIARES.ESTADO_ACTUAL,   AUT_FAMILIARES.DCTO_IDENTIDAD_A,   AUT_FAMILIARES.PARENTESCO_A,   AUT_FAMILIARES.NOMBRE_A,   AUT_FAMILIARES.SEXO_A,   AUT_FAMILIARES.OBSERVACIONES_A,   AUT_FAMILIARES.POLIZA_A,   AUT_FAMILIARES.SALUD_A,   AUT_FAMILIARES.PORCENTAJE_A,   AUT_FAMILIARES.OCUPACION_A,   AUT_FAMILIARES.TELEFONO_A,   AUT_FAMILIARES.POS_A,   AUT_FAMILIARES.AUXILIO_EDUCATIVO_A,   AUT_FAMILIARES.APELLIDO1_A,   AUT_FAMILIARES.APELLIDO2_A,   AUT_FAMILIARES.DIRECCION_A,   AUT_FAMILIARES.ESTADO_ACTUAL_A,   AUT_FAMILIARES.ESTADO,   AUT_FAMILIARES.DESTINATARIO,   AUT_FAMILIARES.SUCURSAL_DESTINATARIO,   AUT_FAMILIARES.TIPO_SOLICITUD,   AUT_FAMILIARES.FECHA_APROBACION,   AUT_FAMILIARES.ENVIADO,   AUT_FAMILIARES.ACTUALIZADO,   AUT_FAMILIARES.RUTA,   AUT_FAMILIARES.CREATED_BY,   AUT_FAMILIARES.DATE_CREATED,   AUT_FAMILIARES.MODIFIED_BY,   AUT_FAMILIARES.DATE_MODIFIED,   AUT_FAMILIARES.N_IDENTIFICACION,   AUT_FAMILIARES.EDAD,   AUT_FAMILIARES.EDAD_A FROM AUT_FAMILIARES

SELECT DISTINCT CARGOS.ID_DE_CARGO, CARGOS.NOMBRE_DEL_CARGO FROM EV_EVALUADOR_EVALUADO EVAL INNER JOIN CARGOS ON EVAL.COMPANIA = CARGOS.COMPANIA AND EVAL.CARGO_EVALUADO = CARGOS.ID_DE_CARGO WHERE EVAL.COMPANIA = :COMPANIA   AND EVAL.CLASE_EVALUACION = :CLASEEVALUACION   AND CARGOS.ID_DE_CARGO >= :CODIGO ORDER BY CARGOS.ID_DE_CARGO

SELECT ROWNUM CODIGO, DECODE (ROWNUM, 1,'Activo',2,'Pensionado',3,'Retirado',4,'Suspensión Preventiva',5,'Activarlo para Ajustes Liquidación',6,'Comisión',7,'Encargos')NOMBRE FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM < 8

SELECT * FROM ( SELECT A.*, ROWNUM RNUM FROM(SELECT * FROM (SELECT  INVENTARIO.CODIGOELEMENTO, INVENTARIO.NOMBRELARGO  FROM INVENTARIO WHERE INVENTARIO.COMPANIA = :COMPANIA AND INVENTARIO.TIPO NOT IN ('C') ORDER BY INVENTARIO.COMPANIA, INVENTARIO.CODIGOELEMENTO) WHERE (CASE WHEN CODIGOELEMENTO IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE UPPER(CODIGOELEMENTO) END)  LIKE UPPER(:CODIGOELEMENTO || '%')  AND (CASE WHEN NOMBRELARGO IS NULL THEN ' ' ELSE UPPER(NOMBRELARGO) END)  LIKE UPPER( '%' || :NOMBRELARGO || '%') ) A WHERE ROWNUM <=  (:PAGINICIO + :PAGTAMANIO)) WHERE RNUM > :PAGINICIO
```

Comment: You should try giving examples of the actual strings you need to parse.

Comment: I have updated with some query's examples.

Comment: Maybe someone else will have a better option, but to me I'd go with string splitting and iterating through the results, but you'll need to implement a fair bit of logic to handle all of the scenarios. Make good use of unit testing!

Comment: The best approach i have for now by far is jsql parser but it is poorly documented. I'm finding a way to deal with it somehow.